# Required tf Transforms in gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, transforms, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In gmapping documents http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping,
and in 5.1.5,5.1.6
says that base_link → odom, and map → odom.

I have try to use map → odom → base_link → base_laser.

1. I don't know "base_link → odom" is right or "odom → base_link" is right? Why?
2. What's the transform formula between odom and base_link?
3. Can I output the transform data(map→odom) from gmapping?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10772/required-tf-transforms-in-gmapping/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. odom -> base_link. You are building a tree starting from a fixed frame and going down the attached things.
2. What do you mean with formula? It should be the robot's motion estimation.
3. Do you mean output for debugging or generate? For the former use tf_echo (or display in rviz), for the latter: Yes, that's what it's supposed to do.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-01**:
I haven't written the package, but I would say that it gets the data from  the odom->base_link transform and the motion model is "hardcoded" as gmapping params (instead of using the covariance).

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-31**:
Why my gmapping node doesn't require /odom? Doesn't Gmapping need to know the position of robot or laser range finder?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-13**:
What could be the reasons of empty map.pgm although it's size is 15.3 MB. Now laser messages are properly published and the tf tree looks ok. But no transform from [/GrndTruth] to frame[/map] and no transform from [/base_GrndTruth to frame[/map]. You can view in details http://answers.ros.org/question/94671/error-in-creating-2d-global-map-of-the-environment/